# VS2010 fails to start with "Unknown Error"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I've just discovered that VS2010 is failing to start. It simply displays a dialog with the message "Unknown Error" on it and then exits.

I suspect this may be related to me uninstalling VS11 beta a few days ago, but am not sure.

Has anyone else experienced this, and got a resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having played around for some time, it seems like the only thing that fixed it was a repair from the VS2010 installer.

The various steps of resetting settings didn't seem to make a difference.

A reinstall of the full .Net Framework 4.0 (not Client Profile) partially fixed things - the IDE would start and load solutions - but I was encountering odd problems like the XML editor not working, and multiple package errors being reported on startup.

So far, with the repair, it seems to be working, but I'll post any further issues if I find them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run [Win + R] -> type `devenv` followed by one param from below.
do same for each param listed below.

**/Rebuild** Cleans and then builds the solution or project with the specified configuration.
**/ResetAddin** Removes commands and command UI associated with the specified Add-in.
**/ResetSettings**Restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to the specified VSSettings file.
**/ResetSkipPkgs**   Clears all SkipLoading tags added to VSPackages.

if still not work, comment me...

Comment: thx for reply - no - tried the middle two of those already, but trying the other two has made no difference either.

Comment: Literally - you start VS2010 - you get nothing, not even splash screen - just a dialog with the simple message "unknown error" and then it exits.